# How to propagate a db id through a Meteor.js Template?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My question touches a common scenario with web apps: you have some kind of db items that map to some kind of sets of DOM items. E.g. a JSON object that maps to a `form` with some fields.

Now imagine that in different locations / on different events inside your form you need that db id. On certain levels (in certain data contexts) the id will be available as `this._id` in Meteor events, but not in all since sub-`#with` statements might overwrite the data context.

What I do currently in those cases is I set in the template containing the form `<form id="{{_id}}" ...>` and then in events where `this._id` is not available I get it via `$(this).closest('form').id`. This works.

But my question is: is there a better way? how would you do it with Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something a lot of us are struggling with... gotta keep that DOM clean amirite?

1. If your DOM hierarchy is predictable, you can use `Template.parentData(n)` to get the parent data context.
2. Alternatively, if there's no relation to the context you need, use `Blaze.getData(el)`. I have a feeling this will become your new best friend. I know as soon as I stumbled upon it I felt like I was cheating it was so easy. 
   Here's my favorite use for it (in an event, iterating over all input fields):

   `var checkFields = t.findAll('input');
   var allGood = true;
   for (var i = 0; i < checkFields.length; i++) {
     if (!simplyValid.validateField(Blaze.getData(checkFields[i]), checkFields[i].value)) allGood = false;
   }`
3. Next, if your top-most module has it's own route, you can store it as an iron router param. This is nice because it sticks the `id` in the url for easy sharing, I personally like clean urls, but other folks love this.
4. Finally, my own pattern is a module-scoped object. In my case, for each route, in the `onCreated` I set my object `window.M = {}`. Then, I fill it up with local collections, a reactive dictionary, and anything else I need. I clear it `onDestroyed`. Sure, it's technically a global, but the scope dies with the module.
5. Eliminate the `#with`:

   `{{#with collection='clients'}}
     {{>subTemplate}}
   {{/with}}
   Becomes
   {{>subTemplate collection= 'clients'}}`
6. Assign the `#with` to an object within the context:
   ```
   {{#with collection='clients'}}
     {{>subTemplate name='foobar'}} //you lose the with context here
   {{/with}}
   Becomes
   {{>subTemplate collection=this name='foobar'}} //you keep context inside an object
7. Access initial parent data via spacebars' double dots & reference that context all the way down `{{>subTemplate parent=..}}`
   ```

Those are all the patterns I currently use to keep a clean DOM. Will be happy to edit if someone else suggests another.

Comment: Thanks! To 1: I don’t like hard coding the DOM structure in JS. It's like `$(...).parent() ... .parent()`. To 2: This is more generally like `Blaze.getData($(...).closest('form'))._id`. This is good. But I would change your example to my snippet here since more simple & more universal. To 3: Yes if you give your items a route, nice! I don't. To 4: I do not really get how a global obj will help me find e.g. what db obj a submit button belongs to. You mean by building a reactive dict with... what? Can you explain?

Comment: For 2, you can avoid the `.closest`, since it's likely that you'll know form element & you can refer to it directly. For 4, an example would be `M.collection = "Clients"` Then your event would be `window[M.collection].insert()`. Of course you should namespace your collections & use a server method, but that's the gist. 

2 more that I just thought about is to do away with `#with` and pass in everything to the template.
Another option is to pass in all the `#with` items into an object like `{{>subTemplate items=this name='foobar'}}`

Comment: Also: at the level of the parent context you want to acces later `{{#each myArr}}{{>subTemplate parent=..}}{{/each}}` and then at sub-sub-levels `{{#each myArr}}{{>subSubTemplate parent=parent}}{{/each}}`.